# Ranging and monitoring stops after a while even with foreground service

Tags: java, android, android-studio, ibeacon, altbeacon

I am using altbeacon library to scan for beacons. I am using a android 8.1 OnePlus 3T. The ranging and monitoring stops after 5 minutes even though I am using a foreground service.
I can see an active notification but detection does not work.

This is my code

This is the main application class

```
    @Override
      public void onCreate() {
          super.onCreate();
          SoLoader.init(this, /* native exopackage */ false);
          startBeacon();
          Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(this);
          builder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
          builder.setContentTitle("Scanning for Beacons");
          Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainApplication.class);
          PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                  this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
          );


          if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
              NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(NotificationChannelId, "Beacons Scanning",
                      NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
              channel.setShowBadge(true);
              channel.setSound(null, null);
              channel.setLightColor(Color.BLUE);
              NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
              assert mNotificationManager != null;
              mNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
              builder = new Notification.Builder(this,
                      NotificationChannelId);
          } else {
              builder = new Notification.Builder(this);
          }

          builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
          beaconManager.enableForegroundServiceScanning(builder.build(), 456);
          beaconManager.setEnableScheduledScanJobs(false);
          beaconManager.setBackgroundBetweenScanPeriod(0);
          beaconManager.setBackgroundScanPeriod(1100);

          Log.d(TAG, "setting up background monitoring for beacons and power saving");
          // wake up the app when a beacon is seen
          Region region = new Region("backgroundRegion",
                  null, null, null);

          regionBootstrap = new RegionBootstrap(this, region);
          backgroundPowerSaver = new BackgroundPowerSaver(this);
          Intent MyIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
          this.startActivity(MyIntent);

      }

      private void startBeacon() {
          beaconManager = BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(getApplicationContext());
          //BeaconManager.setRegionExitPeriod(5000); //5 seconds

          beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser().setBeaconLayout(ALTBEACON));
          beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser().setBeaconLayout(EDDYSTONE_TLM));
          beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser().setBeaconLayout(EDDYSTONE_UID));
          beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser().setBeaconLayout(EDDYSTONE_URL));
          beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser().setBeaconLayout(IBEACON));
      }

    @Override
    public void didEnterRegion(Region region) {
      System.out.println("did enter region");
        if (!beaconManager.isBound(this)) {
            beaconManager.bind(this);
        }
        try {
            beaconManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(new Region("myRangingUniqueId", null, null, null));
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                getNewandOldBeacons(MainApplication.ListofBeacons, "Entry");
            }
        }, 1000);
    }

    @Override
    public void didExitRegion(Region region) {
      System.out.println("did exit region");

        try {
            beaconManager.stopRangingBeaconsInRegion(new Region("myRangingUniqueId", null, null, null));
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        getNewandOldBeacons(MainApplication.ListofBeacons, "Exit");

        if(beaconManager.isBound(this)) {
            beaconManager.unbind(this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void didDetermineStateForRegion(int i, Region region) {

    }

      @Override
      public void onBeaconServiceConnect() {
          beaconManager.setRangeNotifier(new RangeNotifier() {
              @Override
              public void didRangeBeaconsInRegion(Collection<Beacon> beacons, Region region) {
                  if (beacons.size() > 0) {
                      MainApplication.ListofBeacons = beacons;
                  }
              }
          });
      }
```

In MainActivity I simply ask for permissions for ACCESS_COURSE_LOCATION and ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION. The app is in React Native, this is the android native code.

Comment: Can you please set `beaconManager.setDebug(true)` then attach a log that captures the 30 seconds before detections stop up to the point where detections stop?  The log should not filter for your application, so we can see system level log messages, too

Comment: @davidgyoung Mailed you the log Thanks!

Comment: I see an 28 second log showing messages from 15:41:20 to  15:41:38 and it shows beacon detections throughout the log.  When do you see detections stop?  What makes you think they stop?  I suggest adding a log line in didRangeBeaconsInRegion logging the beacon count.

Comment: @davidgyoung Interestingly, once I kill the app and lock the phone, the logs continue to show up till 10-15 minutes but then the logs stop and also detection. Once I press the lock key it continues detection and logging.

Comment: Right, what I really needs to see is a log excerpt showing the last detection and the next 30 seconds.  What I'm looking for is an operating system messaging indicating *why* bluetooth scanning is blocked.  OnePlus probably is doing some kind of operating system customization to do this, and since their modifications are closed source, we must experiment to figure out how they work.  As I don't have a OnePlus device, I'd need you to do the testing to find these log messages (if any).

Comment: @davidgyoung I'll try to check for those log excerpts to find something. Also there's been a peculiar problem. After killing and restarting the app a few times, the app or any other scanner is unable to find any BLE device on that phone.

Comment: @davidgyoung I've sent a log that shows OS level logs to the point where detection stops. The detection start again mysteriously after a few minutes.

Comment: In the latest log shared, I see that the bluetooth service seems to have hung up:  `10-08 16:01:04.710 22646-22666/? E/JavaBinder: !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!  (parcel size = 240)
10-08 16:01:04.711 22646-22666/? E/BtGatt.GattService: Exception: android.os.DeadObjectException: Transaction failed on small parcel; remote process probably died
10-08 16:01:04.718 781-781/? I/vendor.qti.bluetooth@1.0-ibs_handler: DeviceWakeUp: Writing IBS_WAKE_IND`.   This indicates a problem in the device firmware, perhaps caused by its inability to process bluetooth traffic in the conditions under test.

Answer (score 1):

Based on logs provided offline, this appears to be caused by a Qualcomm driver or firmware problem in the OnePlus' bluetooth stack.  This is shown in the following log excerpt:

`10-08 16:01:04.710 22646-22666/? E/JavaBinder: !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!! (parcel size = 240) 
10-08 16:01:04.711 22646-22666/? E/BtGatt.GattService: Exception: android.os.DeadObjectException: Transaction failed on small parcel; remote process probably died 
10-08 16:01:04.718 781-781/? I/vendor.qti.bluetooth@1.0-ibs_handler: DeviceWakeUp: Writing IBS_WAKE_IND`

Unfortunately, there is probably nothing you can do to prevent this.  When the phone gets into this state, you might try turning bluetooth off and back on to see if it clears the condition (this is the equivalent of a  'reset').  If so, then you might be able to use the Android Beacon Library's BluetoothMedic class to automate turning bluetooth off/on when the problem comes up.  But this is clearly an imperfect solution at best.

Comment: Great, but still does not explain why would it kill the foreground service. That should persist right?

Comment: @DivyeShah, I'm just going by what is in the logs you share with me.  The shared log shows that the bluetooth stack hangs up.  I did not see any evidence in that log of the foreground service being killed in that log.

Comment: I'll try to capture that and send. Btw how can I use the bluetooth medic to deal with this exception?

Comment: See here: https://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/javadoc/org/altbeacon/bluetooth/BluetoothMedic.html